# Matlab transfer function to observability canonical form

Tags: matlab

I really need your help on this, Let's say I have an original TF2(see  code below), I would like to transform it to state-space. And from that state space, I want to get the transfer function again. As you can see this is probably a loop, however I couldn't get the same transfer function using the observability canonical form. Any idea?

```
syms m1 m2 b ks kd s;
TF2=-1*((s^2*m1+ks+s*b)/(s^2*m2+s*kd)) %Original TF
A=[0 0;1 -kd/m2]
B=[-ks/m2; -b/m2+((kd*m1)/(m2*m2))]
C=[0 1]
D=[-m1/m2]
phi=s*eye-A
TF=C*inv(phi)*B+D %TF from observability canonical form
```

This is the formula for observability canonical form:

[image]

where
[image]

And this is the answer i get:

```
TF =

(ks*(s - 1))/(s*(kd + m2)) - (m2*(b/m2 - (kd*m1)/m2^2))/(kd + m2) - m1/m2


TF2 =

-(m1*s^2 + b*s + ks)/(m2*s^2 + kd*s)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, note that `TF` has not been simplified. If you try `simplify(TF)` will give `-(ks + b*s - ks*s + m1*s)/(s*(kd + m2))` which is still not the same, but quite close. There may be some minor error in your state space equations

Comment: I cant find errors in your `A,B,C,D` so my guess its in the next two lines. You just have an extra `-ks*s`

Comment: Just to be sure: you really need to do that symbolically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `s*eye` is actually `s*1` and whenever you perform addition/subtraction with matrices and scalars, the scalar is automatically multiplied with a **`ones`** matrix and not with an **`eye`** matrix.

Hence your resulting `phi` is actually

```
[s | s]
[-----] - A
[s | s]
```

and not

```
[s | 0]
[-----] - A
[0 | s]
```

which should have been the latter. You can fix it by using `eye(2)`.

For such symbolic calculations, it's always handy to compute the determinant of `phi` which would be the denominator anyways to see if you are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I've made such mistake!

Comment: @Jdane My pleasure. We all get blind sometimes.